# Change post_date to post_modified date on post template?

Tags: posts, templates, post-meta

I'm looking to change the post created date to a modified date on my post template (single.php). Moreso, I'm looking to control when I update that date based on whether I make significant changes to the post.

I'm thinking I might have to create a custom field as well as an option box in the edit post screen to set the custom field. Maybe there's a simpler way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this into the loop or if you want to change created date to modified date than replace that with below code. As I know this feature works from all version of wordpress after 2.1

```
<?php the_modified_date(); ?>
```

More detail you can find here http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/the_modified_date

Comment: Actually, because I'm working with the Suffusion theme, the date is included in the title. The only workaround I have come across is to change the post date itself to the post modified date.